# Script.js is minified. How should I find the module responsible for this?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, minified-js

I've inherited code for a project, Magento 1.9. For the task at hand, I need to touch a JavaScript file located at

```
skin/frontend/my_projects_name/default/release/js/script.js
```

This script was originally minified. To make changes, because I don't know how it was minified, I've used a program to "un-minify" it manually. Is this file common among Magento 1.9 projects, or is it unique to this codebase? There are several JS files. Which file was this minified from?

In the `skin/frontend/my_projects_name/default` dir, there are multiple dependencies files:

- bower.json
- Gruntfile.js
- gulpfile.js
- package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be unique to my codebase indeed. There was a "gulp" script (see gulp.js), which compiles stylesheets and script files. In order to make JS changes, I needed to run

```
gulp watch
```

similar to a scss compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find the original JS file it to go to your server on the command line and use `grep` to find the line, not the most beautiful solution, but it get's the job done:

`grep -r 'your statement' *`

Comment: Are you sure, on our M1 projects we don't have `release/js/script.js`.

Comment: @BenCrook You might be right about that one, let me check and edit my answer

Comment: I have found this file though - `skin/frontend/enterprise/default/js/scripts.js`. So it may be a symlink from `enterprise/default` but only OP can check that.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it's unique to your codebase as I haven't ever seen a directory called `release` inside the skin directory. Nor do any of our M1 projects have `scripts.js` in the themes scripts directory (except the enterprise default theme).

**Unless** it's referring to this file and the `release` directory is a symlink that changes on each release?

```
skin/frontend/enterprise/default/js/scripts.js
```

If this is the case it's responsible for some enterprise features.

To see if this is the case check the first few lines after the comments (line 27 and 28), do they look like this?

```
Validation.defaultOptions.immediate = true;
Validation.defaultOptions.addClassNameToContainer = true;
```